How to determine the quiver of $R[x]/(x^2)$ for a finite dimensional $k$-algebra?
Let $R$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra given by a quiver. Then what is the quiver $R[x]/(x^2)$?
For example, an algebra is given by the following quiver
$$1\stackrel{\alpha}\rightarrow2$$
$$1\stackrel{\alpha, \beta}\rightleftharpoons2 \text{ with }\alpha\beta=0$$
$$1\circlearrowleft \text{with } rad^2=0$$
then what is the quiver of $R[x]/(x^2)$?

(Did you actually check how your question compiles?)

I can't read your diagrams, but just add an extra loop marked $x$ at each vertex, and relations saying these loops square to zero and commute with all arrows that were already there.

Thank you! I edit it again.
